# python : how to add number between them, when is digit is TRUE

Tags: python, database, data-analysis

I have a problem, I want to add some number between them, but only for some condition, I have a list from web scraping with number and space, the number is a time a soccer match is played by the player, and the space is if the player have score during this match, 1 space = 1 goal, 2 space = 2 goal 3 space : 3 goal.

So when I import in a excel I can make a rule color, with "space" and see really quick witch match he have scored or not.

Now I want to know, since how many min the player have not score, and when it score, the counter of min reset to 0.

So I wrote this :

```
    for list in lists:
        
        go = list.find('td', class_="tj1").text.replace('\xa0', '').replace("'","")
        goo = [go]
        print(goo)
```

and the result is :

```
['90   ']
['90 ']
['90   ']
['90   ']
['90 ']
['68 ']
['27']
['90']
['78 ']
```

As you can see, there is space in the string, it's the number of score the player have done in this match ( here it's Neymar ), you can see there is two result here :

```
['27']
['90']
```

there is no space, so the player have no score in there match, so I have to tell python, to add the number between them and tell me the result as " MAX MIN WITHOUT SCORE "

and the count : " NOT SCORE A GOAL SINCE ? MIN ", if the player score, the count : "NOT SCORE A GOAL SINCE ? MIN " reset to 0.

So I wrote this

```
for list in lists:
        
        
        go = list.find('td', class_="tj1").text.replace('\xa0', '').replace("'","")
        goo = [go]
        
        print(go)
        x = go.isdigit()
        print(x)
```

and the result is :

```
90   
False
90 
False
90   
False
90   
False
90 
False
68 
False
27
True
90
True
78 
False
```

So now, python can see witch one have space, and which one don't have, so my question, how can I do for add number with the condition "True" and tell me the " MAX MIN WHITOUT SCORING " and reset to zero if in the next match it's score for having " NOT SCORED SINCE ? MIN "

I hope I was clear in my question, thanks for your time, it's very appreciated.

some exemple of what I want :

```
90   
False
90 
False
90   
False
90   
False
90 
False
68 
False
27
True
90
True
78 
False
```

Result :

```
MAX MIN WITHOUT SCORING = 90 + 27 = 117 min

NOT SCORED SINCE ? MIN = 0 min
```

other exemple :

```
90   
True
90 
True
90   
True
90   
False
90 
False
68 
False
27
False
90
True
78 
True
```

Result :

```
MAX MIN WITHOUT SCORING = 90 + 90 = 90 = 270 min

NOT SCORED SINCE ? MIN = 90 + 78 = 168 min
```

Comment: in the example, what does `['27']` mean ?  that the player played 27 minutes and did not score ?  and if so why represent like this and not a dict which is more suitable for storing this data `{"mins":27, "goals":0}`  ..?

Comment: yes 27 is the minutes played and did not score, for a dict I'm little new at python, I don't know how store a data web sraped in dico with this automatically indication "no space = 0 goal" " space = goal" can you detail a little how can I do please ?

Comment: i will post this as an aswer...

Comment: Could you provide a little examples of that HTML or provide an url of the website you scraped from, maybe there is a better way to get your "goal"

Answer (score 0):

if appears as though the method for storing data as lists with spaces is suboptimal.

a richer form of storage would be as a `dict` or a `list-of-dicts` which would look like this:

```
d = [
    {"mins":90, "goals":0},
    {"mins":90, "goals":0},
    {"mins":90, "goals":2},
    {"mins":27, "goals":0}
]
```

in particular, because the dict has richer data, for example, you could add other fields (called `keys`):

```
d = [
    {"player name":"ronaldo", "mins":27, "goals":0},
    {"player name":"messi", "mins":27, "goals":5}
]
```

There other formats too.

The advantage is that you can access the dict like this:

```
print(d[0])
print(d[0]['player name'])
print(d[0]['mins'])
```

which would give this:

```
{'player name': 'ronaldo', 'mins': 27, 'goals': 0}
ronaldo
27
```

I hope this helps you progress.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond, but if I understand correctly, it's mean if I use this method I have to update manually the score and the minute for each player ( I have 180 players for now )

i have some trouble to understand how I can transfer the result of the web scraping multiple <td> to a dic